# How to check if two objects are touching in unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a car in Unity and I want to make it jump. I only want it to jump when it is touching the ground. I was wondering how I can make a collision checker in the function I made. The isJumping is checking for a key being pressed in FixedUpdate()

Ground definition:

```cs
public GameObject ground;
```

Function so far:

```cs
private void HandleJumping()
    {
        if(isJumping==true){
            transform.Translate (0f, 1f, 0f);  

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there are multiple ways, here are some:

#### Check if the car has collided with the ground or not

```cs
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision) {
    if(collision.gameObject == ground) {
        isJumping = false;
    }
}
```

---

#### Check if the velocity along Y-axis of the car is zero

If your car has a rigidbody component, check it's velocity along Y-axis is zero or not, if it is, that means the car is on the ground

```cs
if(gameObject.rigidbody.velocity.y == 0) {
    isJumping = false;
}
```